# Where are ServiceStack security bulletins posted?

Tags: servicestack

We have developed a PA-DSS payment application that makes use of ServiceStack and part of the PA-DSS requirements is to monitor for security vulnerabilities / updates from product vendors used.

While I see the release notes, I do not see any security specific entries, Demis, where are you guys publishing this information?

Thanks

Comment: They would be published on the release notes, we've not had any security bulletins to date, but we have some made changes from concerns raised in issues, e.g. [generating new session ids on auth](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#generate-new-session-cookies-on-authentication).

Comment: Thanks mythz. I figured that was the case, but wanted to make sure.